# Zend Framework - Regex Routes and Url View Helper Issue

Tags: regex, zend-framework, routes, view-helpers

I have this route setup in one of my bootstrap files...

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'user/(\d+)',
    array(
        'module'        => 'user',
        'controller'    => 'view',
        'action'        => 'index'
    ),
    array(
        1 => 'id'
    ),
    'user/%d'
);
$router->addRoute('user', $route);
```

I am then trying to use the view url helper to buld a href but I keep getting the error 'Cannot assemble. Too few arguments?'.

This is the code for my helper that is generating the link:

```
$this->view->url(array('controller'=>'user', 'action' => $userID), 'user');
```

If I take out the 'user' part of the url then it doesnt error but the link doesnt always display correctly.
I thought this was the name and should refer to the name I have entered under addRoute.

I have played with different settings but I continue to receive an error. Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$this->view->url(array('id' => $userId), 'user', true);
```

do not need to supply controller/action again as it's defined in the route (second param), the third param (true) will reset the params from the current request.